# Eclipse automatically creates a breakpoint in ThreadPoolExecutor class

Tags: android, json, eclipse, android-debug

I am creating an app in which I'm calling an asmx service. Service works fine in browser, but in android every time I run my app eclipse will create automatic breakpoint in ThredPoolExecutor class[ in runWorker() method at w.lock()]. I tried to remove it manually only to know that file is not editable. Remove all breakpoints didn't work. what should I do?![Breakpoint at w.lock()][1]

Comment: Did you using mac or windows pc

Comment: Windows pc. I think some thread is blocking others and never getting out of it i.e deadlocked. but i dont know how to tackle it down